# Calculate Average of Time(7) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am making an attendance system in which I will add monthly records of employee time in and time out. At the end of the month average time in and time out will be created.

Please tell me how to apply `avg()` to datatype of `time(7)`?

```
declare @tblPK table
(
    timeinat varchar(13) not null,
    timeoutat varchar(13) not null
) ;

insert into @tblPK 
select cast((onattendance) as varchar(13))ONTime, 
       cast((offattendance) as varchar(13))OFFTime 
from t_attendancedetails ;

select * from @tblPK ;
```

This is only giving output of all entries.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. Why aren't you storing timeinat and timeoutat as time fields? Also, why are you casting them back to the exact same type they already are?

Comment: dude, in my table i am storing time(7) object, this code demonstrate a temporary table in which i used varchar(13). so i only want a way to calculate the average. please suggest. t_attendancedetails table contains time object

Comment: no i want only time not date @MarvinLabs

Comment: Tip 1: Don't store times in a varchar field. The query will be a lot easier if you use the proper type, especially since i see no good reason to use varchar in the first place. Use the Time Data type

Comment: @Atif Imtiaz: I thought you would be smart enough to get the idea about how to extract part of a date/time and do an average (time or date is no different).

Comment: And follow @JohnFx's suggestion. Store your time/dates as long values (for instance time since the epoch in the GMT time zone).

Comment: @MarvinLabs i thought you would be somewhat reasonable. for your kind information i am storing time in a time datatype this query was just meant for calculating average. at the backend i have used time object. dont get confused with the query it is fault, since i am unable to apply avg() to time object so i thought it would be better to first save the data in temporary table as varchar and then calculate the average. now what?

Comment: Would it be enough to use a precision of millisecond for calculation of average?

Comment: instead of asking questions you can suggest the answer if you have @MikaelEriksson

Comment: I think this should be re-opened. The linked "duplicate" is a question for Teradata. But this is for SQL-Server and date-time functions differ. No answer there can be used for this question, only as a scetch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculating average with a precision of millisecond using `time(7)` columns.

```
select dateadd(millisecond, avg(datediff(millisecond, onattendance, offattendance)), cast('00:00' as time(7)) )
from t_attendancedetails
```

The query uses `datediff`to get the difference in milliseconds between `onattendance` and `offattendance`. Then it uses the aggregate function `avg` to calculate the average difference in milliseconds and finally it uses `dateadd` to add the average number of milliseconds to the `time(7)` value `00:00`.

Ref:
[DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)
[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
[AVG (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)
[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

**Update:**

When calculating the average with a precision of `time(7)` you need to split the time in two parts because `datediff` and `dateadd` does not deal with `bigint`.

The time difference values is converted to nanoseconds before average is calculated and the conversion back to `time(7)` is done in two steps, first the seconds and then the nanoseconds.

```
declare @T0 time(7) = '00:00:00'
declare @G bigint = 1000000000  
declare @H bigint = 100         

select dateadd(nanosecond, cast(right(T.A, 9) as int), dateadd(second, T.A / @G, @T0))
from
  (
  select avg(
              @G * datediff(second, @T0, offattendance) + @H * right(offattendance, 7) -
              @G * datediff(second, @T0, onattendance ) + @H * right(onattendance,  7)
            )
  from t_attendancedetails
  ) as T(A)
```

Comment: now that is called the REAL answer. it worked. i am new to sql so i know little about it. :)

Comment: @AtifImtiaz Added a bit of explanation as well.

Comment: Another way is just to convert the datediff result to bigint: select dateadd(millisecond, avg(convert(bigint,datediff(millisecond, onattendance, offattendance))), cast('00:00' as time(7)) )
from t_attendancedetails